# SQL join with with where and having count() condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause, having

I have 2 tables

**Sleep_sessions** [id, user_id, (some other values)]

**Tones** [id, sleep_sessions.id (FK), (some other values)]

I need to select 10 sleep_sessions where user_id = 55 and where each sleep_session record has at least 2 tone records associated with it.

I currently have the following;

```
SELECT `sleep_sessions`.*
FROM (`sleep_sessions`)
JOIN `tones` ON sleep_sessions.id = `tones`.`sleep_session_id`
WHERE `user_id` = 55
GROUP BY `sleep_sessions`.`id`
HAVING count(tones.id) > 4
ORDER BY `started` desc
LIMIT 10
```

However I've noticed that count(tone.id) is basically the entire of the tones table and not the current sleep_session being joined

Many thanks for your help,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what went wrong with your query. Maybe, try

```
HAVING count(*)
```

The following query might be a bit more readable (having can be a bit of a pain to understand):

```
SELECT *
FROM (`sleep_sessions`)
WHERE `user_id` = 55
AND (SELECT count(*) FROM `tones` 
     WHERE `sleep_sessions`.`id` = `tones`.`sleep_session_id`) > 4
ORDER BY `started` desc
LIMIT 10
```

The advantage of this is the fact that you won't mess up the wrong semantics you have created between your `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses. Only MySQL would ever accept your original query. Here's some insight:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: thank you very much sir :) Can I ask, have I done something wrong in either my choice of select OR my database set up? Or is this an acceptable query?

Comment: @Garbit: I'd be careful with `GROUP BY` in MySQL. It's the only database that allows this illegal `GROUP BY` SQL syntax. This will open pandora's box, specifically when combining with `HAVING` and `ORDER BY`